# Clang emits an "unused type alias" warning for a type alias that is used

Tags: c++, clang, clang++, llvm-clang, type-alias

I have some code that Clang is generating a warning for. This is simplified from the actual code, but the spirit is the same. `this_t` in the local class is used to instantiate some other template class.

```cpp
template<class T>
struct value_holder
{
    T  value;
};

template<class T>
int get_value()
{
    struct value_t
    {
        using this_t = value_t;
        //    ^ here
        static value_holder<this_t> val()
        {
            return value_holder<this_t>();
        }

        operator int()
        { return 0; }
    };
    return value_t::val().value;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return get_value<void>();
}
```

When compiled with `-std=c++1z -Wall`, Clang warns about `unused type alias`:

```
main.cpp:14:15: warning: unused type alias 'this_t' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
        using this_t = value_t;
              ^
1 warning generated.
```

You can see the error on godbolt ([6.0](https://godbolt.org/g/3xuVWp), [trunk](https://godbolt.org/g/DbZeBA)) and locally I'm using Clang 7 which reports the same thing.

This warning only appears when the local class is nested in a template function or method of a template class. When the class is nested in a concrete class or function there is no warning.

Is Clang correct to emit this warning here? The `this_t` type is used in the return type of `value_t::val()`.

Comment: @VTT It is used in the definition of `val()` so it definitely seems like it's not an "unused" type alias. If you take out the `using` the code doesn't compile.

Comment: My guess is that after having resolved the template type, when it compiles the concrete code, it has some `value_holder_value_t` class and "forgot" that it used `this_t` to resolve the template type.

Comment: In the godbolt output, note the return type in the signature `int get_value<void>()::value_t::val()`. Somehow it is recognizing that the type `value_holder<value_t>` will never be seen outside of `get_value()` and is "optimizing" the function signature.

Comment: I set `-Wno-unused-local-typedef` years ago and have never looked back

Comment: Remember that POSIX reserves all names ending in `_t` for use by the implementation, so such names are usually a bad choice for your own types/functions/aliases.

Comment: @JesperJuhl oof, that's disappointing... thanks for saying something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it is a bug in Clang ([24883](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24883), [33298](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33298)), first reported in 2015 against Clang 3.7. I tried in godbolt and it appears to occur as far back as 3.6.